# Keeping KEY of all streams same as the source stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I am getting data into the source topic with keys and values in AVRO schema. I have 2 more streams in the pipeline downstream before I am sending the data into MySQL. But since I am using functions from KSQL the key from the source is not getting mapped into the downstream streams.

The keys are of a composite type. Is there any way where I can do some transformations on the key values and keep the KEYS in downstream streams too?

I tried multiple ways and know that if use SELECT AS statement during CREATE STREAM statement will keep the KEY intact but any transformations remove the KEY from the streams.

Example:

```
-- source stream
CREATE STREAM TEST_1 
  (COL1 STRING, COL2 STRING, COL3 STRING) 
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='TEST_1', PARTITIONS=1, REPLICAS=1, VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');

-- Second stream 
CREATE STREAM TEST_2 
   WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='TEST_2', PARTITIONS=1, REPLICAS=1, VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO') AS 
   SELECT CLEAR(COL1) AS COL1, CLEAR(COL2) AS COL2, CLEAR(COL3) AS COL3 
     FROM TEST_1;
```

Here the TEST_1 is from a database. It has composite keys (COL1, COL2).

But when I am creating stream TEST_2 the composite keys are not reflected from TEST_1. 
I need the keys for tombstone records for delete operation in MySQL. There are some cleaning operations performed on the keys.

I am using Kafka confluent for this. The insert and update operations don't have any problem as I had an SMT - value to a key, in the sink connectors.

Here CLEAR() is a custom UDF. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but maybe a custom partitioner could help?

Comment: The problem is specifically with `DELETE` operations. Any delete operation from the source database generates a tombstone record where the `KEY` field will have the primary key values and the `VALUE` field will be `null`. The `KEY` field values will have to use the custom UDF `CLEAR(VARCHAR)`. I am not able to use that in this case. I was thinking if this will require writing a custom consumer and producer that will consume the record and do the processing on the `KEY` field values and then push into a stream.

Comment: Till now Kafka confluent does not support any other format in the key in streams other than string. So the keys cannot be kept in any format other than string in streams. I can see the issue open in GitHub page.

Comment: This restriction is already relaxed and simple/primitive key types like integer, long and similar are already support: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/syntax-reference/#key-requirements -- there is more WIP to also support complex (ie, multi-column) keys.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information. I am currently using confluent 5.4.1. It will be a huge benefit if record type, avro is also supported. :)

Comment: If you want DELETEs / Tombstones to flow through, then you may want to import the topic as a TABLE rather than a STREAM. A table will respect the tombstones.

While ksqlDB does not yet support multiple key columns, it will copy across any key data untouched if your statements don't include any `PARTITION BY`, `GROUP BY` or `JOIN`s.

However, if you need to change the data in the key, then you'll need to wait until ksqlDB supports structured keys (https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/projects/9), or switch to a Kafka Streams based solution.